# List index out of range when iterating in a loop - Python

Tags: python-3.x, indexoutofboundsexception

I am working on leave-one-out model validation process. When I run in through a loop leaving one item of the list for test it stops when i = 19. But when I just run in one by one manually with i = 19 it runs fine. Length of features is 36.

```
for i in range(len(features)):
        # i = 18
        w_count = word_count[i]
        x_test_c = features[i][['count']].copy()
        x_test = features[i]
        x_test.drop('count', axis=1, inplace=True)
        x_train_list = features
        x_train_list.pop(i)
        y_test = summaries[i]
        y_train_list = summaries
        y_train_list.pop(i)

        x_train = merge_data(x_train_list)
        x_train.drop('count', axis=1, inplace=True)
        y_train = merge_data(y_train_list)
        print(x_train.shape,"\t",y_train.shape)
        print(x_test.shape,"\t",y_test.shape)

        model = sm.OLS(y_train, x_train, missing='drop').fit()

        predictions = model.predict(x_test)
        predictions = predictions.sort_values(ascending=False)

        print("\n\nLeave one out cross validation \nTest report:",i+1)
        match(predictions, w_count, x_test_c, y_test)
```

Sample output is like this.

```
(sysenv) D:\pythonprojects\rec_proj>python main.py 
Leave one out cross validation
Test report: 1
total word count of report: 509
summary word count: ~ 127.25
['2.4', '1.5', '3.2']
Precision= 1.0
Recall= 0.21428571428571427
F1= 0.35294117647058826
....
Leave one out cross validation
Test report: 18
total word count of report: 380
summary word count: ~ 95.0
['5.3', '12.2', '1.14', '5.2']
Precision= 0.75
Recall= 0.12
F1= 0.20689655172413793
```

It stops after this iteration.
Erorr is like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 49, in <module>
    lou(df_len, df_summary, word_count)
  File "D:\pythonprojects\rec_proj\model_eval.py", line 33, in lou
    x_test_c = features[i][['count']].copy()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But if I plug i = 18

```
Leave one out cross validation
Test report: 19
total word count of report: 741
summary word count: ~ 185.25
['3.10', '10.1', '2.2', '4.1', '5.3', '2.4']
Precision= 0.8333333333333334
Recall= 0.22727272727272727
F1= 0.35714285714285715
```

So found that loop failed at 18, 27, 30, 33, 35. I couldn't debug this because it works fine when plugging those values manually.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `range(n)` will yield all the numbers from `0` to `n`. To help visualize your problem, imagine we have this simple program:

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for m in range(len(array)): # len(array) evaluates to 5
    print(m) 
for n in array:
    print(n)
```

The output (replacing newlines with spaces) would be:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4
```

As you can see, `range(len(array))` went further than the length of the array. This is where your code comes in. In the first line, you start a for loop that will loop over `range(len(features))`, but then in the fourth line you access `features[i]`. Thus, on the last iteration of the loop, `range` oversteps the length of the array, and Python throws an error because the code tries to access an element of `features` that isn't there.

Comment: I get your point. But if you have read the entire post, you can see it stops at i = 17. Length of features is 36. Since it failed at 17 I changed `range(17, len(features))` and so on. That's how I figure other i's that the same error occurs.

Comment: Plus your answer for 1st loop seems to incorrect according to [this](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/). I am using python 3.6. I just tested whether my loop going from 0 to 36. No it stops at 35.

Comment: Huh. I must have been thinking of something different on the range function. I'll take it down.